# Android Reminder: Difficulty in setting Form validation

Tags: android

I am Planning to implement a form validation in android. I have done empty field validation using the below code.(for Edit Text mTitleText )

---

```
mTitleText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  if( mTitleText.getText().toString().length() == 0 )     
    mTitleText .setError( "This Fieid should not be empty " );
  }
}
```

---

But the problem is that even when the form page is opened it shows error due to empty field.
Seethe picture. Is there any thing other than onfocus change that i can use? 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/507/screenshotsd.png/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

```
mTitleText.setVisible(View.GONE);
```

at form page load (means onResume)

and update it

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

 if( mTitleText.getText().toString().length() == 0 )     
    mTitleText .setError( "This Fieid should not be empty " );
    mTitleText.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). You'll probably be needing the [`afterTextChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29)-method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not test the form when it is submitted (meaning, test all the fields once the user presses the "submit" button)? What's the impetus for testing each field as it loses focus?